# Instant Payment Notification (IPN)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have more than one website that I want to use IPN with. However, there is only one notification URL to edit in this feature? So how it is possible to support mult-website?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in the notification url on the initial post to PayPal (assuming the NVP integration) using the parameter: notify_url
You many have the ability to pass in the notification url in other implementations.

The setting in PayPal, is the default one I think.

Comment: So you mean I have a to some coding in my sites?

Comment: It depends on the integration, if its your own custom integration, then yes, if its a CMS, hopefully there is a configuration setting or other way of doing it.